# React state change doesn't rerender cloned children

Tags: reactjs, recursion, state, children

I have a stateful component, Form.  In the constructor I create state, then I iterate the components children.  I clone the target children and add props using

```
 React.cloneElement(x, {data: modelProperty});
```

where modelProperty is an object with a piece of this.state on it. Because of the cloning I end up with a different instance of this.props.children.  So in render I render my new collection of children that have been decorated with a piece of the parents this.state.

I would expect that his would create a binding between state and children such that when state changes the children that are effected are rerendered.  However, while the parent component ( Form ) does rerender, the children that are effected by the state change do not re-render.

This is probably a bit confusing so I will post some code.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    fields: props.fields,
    formIsValid: true
  };
  this.newChildren = decorateInputs(this.props.children, this.state.fields);
}
```

then

```
const decorateInput = (children, fields) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, x => {
    if(!x.props){ return x; }
    if (x.props.frfProperty) {
      var field = fields.filter(f => f.name === x.props.frfProperty)[0];
      if (!field) {
        throw new Error(`No property on model with name: ${x.frfProperty}!`)
      }
      return React.cloneElement(x, {data: field});
    }

    var clonedItems = decorateInput(x.props.children, fields);
    return React.cloneElement(x, {children: clonedItems});
  })
};

export default decorateInput;
```

then

```
render() {
  return (<form onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this)} >
    {this.newChildren}
  </form>)
}
```

Now one quick fix is to do the decoration in the render method but this renders ALL the child components again, not just the ones whose state changed.

My basic question is why is the re-render behavior broken, or not present on the cloned children.

Lastly, I know there are other patterns which will work.  My question is about the mechanics of doing it this way.  i.e. I know about Redux and I know I could have my own wrapper for the children provided to the consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding you mentioned isn't happned automagically.
I think it should be enough to put the decoration call in `componentWillUpdate()` callback **as well**.

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
 this.newChildren = decorateInputs(nextProps.children, nextState.fields);
}
```

Read more about [compontent lifecycle.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

Comment: Interesting.  And true. That worked.  I did update all my children though, not just the one whose state I changed.  But perhaps that can't be avoided because of the recursion and cloning.

Comment: @Raif I think it might be a smell of bad design. Rendering is just a reflection of the state. If you change the state and you want to render only part of the children maybe these children haven't interested this state at all? Maybe you should move them to another component?

Comment: well, the situation is that these are inputs in a form, when the onChange event is triggered it updates state for just that one input.  I'd rather not re-render every input on every keystroke

Comment: well, while I don't really like the fact that it works this way, I guess that doesn't make this not the right answer, so I will mark it as such.